# Julia Client in Atom - Internal Stack Overflow Error

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I've come across this annoying problem that I haven't found anywhere else. I've being using Julia in Atom for at least a few months, but suddenly today the console becomes unresponsive when I try to edit a file. Switching focus to a new file seems to cause some code to run in the background, which prevents me from executing any other code in the console.

Eventually an 'Internal Error' window pops up saying that there is a stack overflow error, which tells me that something hidden is endlessly running in the background.

Any ideas on what it could be?

The error output from ctrl-alt-I is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) cancelled by julia
misc.coffee:10 
Julia Boot: 717.02s
internal/process/next_tick.js:103 Uncaught (in promise) cancelled by julia
internal/process/next_tick.js:103 Uncaught (in promise) cancelled by julia_tickCallback @ internal/process/next_tick.js:103
```

Comment: I suggest that rather than asking on Stack Overflow, you shoukd file a bug report with the makes of the Plugin (Juno?)
This seems pretty clear to be a bug.